# convert date from 2013-08-22T10:47:12+02:00 to 2013-08-22 10:47:12

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

Hy guys,

I would like to know how convert date with timezone like  `2013-08-22T10:47:12+02:00` to another date `2013-08-22 10:47:12`.

I try to  do that with `SimpleDateFormat` object, but I have the same exception:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-08-22T10:47:12+02:00"`

Can you help me? thanks

**UPDATE**

I show here my failing code:

```
        String CURRENT_TIME_PATTERN ="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:yyX";
        String NEW_TIME_PATTERN ="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        String data="2013-08-22T10:47:12+02:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(CURRENT_TIME_PATTERN);
        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat(NEW_TIME_PATTERN);
        Date d = sdf.parse(data);
        String formattedTime = output.format(d);
        System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

In this manner I will have exception over invalid parameter 'X'.

If I use this pattern   `String CURRENT_TIME_PATTERN ="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";`, I'll get unparsable date exception.

Comment: Which format did you use for parsing?

Comment: So you just want to turn the T into a space, and drop everything from the + onwards?

Comment: You should follow a tutorial about Date parsing.

Comment: This is the format that I except:`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz` and that is the new one I would like to convert the date `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Since your input format is ISO 8601 style, try `X` ("ISO 8601 time zone") instead of `z` ("general time zone").

Comment: Are you telling me like this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`? .I already tried but he gives me: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'` exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to do any date and time formatting / parsing.

With the following imports:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

And the following code:

```
String input = "2013-08-22T10:47:12+02:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatterA = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTimeFormatter formatterB = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = formatterA.parseDateTime(input);
String output = dateTime.toString(formatterB);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but why he doesn't work id I use SimpleDateFormat object from `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. He give me always the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this if you always have `T` within your `String` :

```
    String s = "2013-08-22T10:47:12+02:00";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:yyX"); // here X is for ISO 8601 time zone
    Date parseDate = formatter.parse(s);
    formatter.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:yy");
    String formattedStr = formatter.format(parseDate);
    System.out.println(formattedStr);
```

- doc for [ISO 8601 time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)

**Update :** removed `String#replace()` method and changed the formatter pattern to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:yyX"`.

Comment: I tried but he gives me: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X' exception.`

Comment: will you put your code in the question by editing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        String date = "2013-08-22T10:47:12+02:00";
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String myDate = dateFormat1.format(date1);
        System.out.println("Date :: " + myDate);
```